# Custom module not showing in Odoo 10 (Windows 7, IDE Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, odoo, odoo-10

I have creating a simple module in Odoo10 but its not showing in the Apps list. I upgraded few times but still am unable to view it.

```
{
    'name': 'ABC',
    'version': '1.0',
    'category': 'Testing',
    'description': """Test""",   
    'depends': ['sale'],
    'author': 'xxxx',
    'data': [              
        'views/abc_views.xml',
    ],
    'demo': [],
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
}
```

I dnt know what parameter or thing im missing here.
Hopes for suggestion

Comment: yes I have changed the name of file

Comment: How do you start odoo in Eclipse? Do you use a config file? And when you do, do you have set the addons path to your module?

Comment: have you added `__init__.py` , if you have not define any model still you need to add blank `__init__.py` file

Comment: You need to restart server and upgraded list the model.

Comment: just give permission 777 to custom addons folder and make sure you include path of custom addons folder in config file.

Comment: Will we can't judge what did you missed from the snap you posted, as far as I understand you upgrade the module (so it is existed in the apps) and you did not find it in the main page, right? 
is their at least one class and one view in your module?